# 2 players on 1 PC

Tags: windows, virtualization, gaming, windows-server, multiple-users

I have a really good PC, Ryzen 1700x, GTX 1080Ti, all watercooled and overclocked and for now I was just playing alone and all was easy out of the box, but now my wife is interested in gaming, and want to play with me but since she's a casual gamer, it would be really expensive to buy a whole gaming machine (at least 500€ for something that could handle the game she wants to play : PUBG and this would be the strict minimum).
So I thought my machine would be powerful enough to handle two games at the same time so I tested some things :

## Multi session on windows:

- With a little tweak, one can enable multi session even on Windows 10 (I know this is not really legal but I didn't want to format and test with Windows Server Essential just to see at the end that it didn't worked, I wanted to test it before) and I thought it would be good if she connects to my PC with RDP and play through it, that confirmed that my PC is powerful enough to handle two games at the same times with reasonable performances (it was APEX legends and PUBG at the same time, without even changing anything in graphics preferences), but RDP is definitely not optimized for that so the latency for her was really huge and there was issues with her mouse in a FPS game played like this.
- Another thing I thought was to launch her session through another session in windows, run steam and use the steam local stream on her computer to play the game distantly but for unknown reasons, this didn't worked for now (her computer didn't see the distant steam session and it was impossible to run local stream)
- I think about one last thing with this tweak, would it be possible for me to separate my desktop in two, giving her a screen, a keyboard and a mouse independantly than mines and have an isolation between the two sets of peripherals for her to run a windows session while I run mine, but not through RDP this time but directly with peripherals connected to the computer ?

The advantage is that I don't have to change anything of my hardware. The default is that I will have to buy a Windows Server, but this can be found out there.

## Virtualization

I also thought about virtualization like Linus tech tips did in a video, not with unraid but with PCI passthrough on a free linux distro with KVM, but I need good performances (because PUBG is not really a well-optimized game) and this would make me buy at least another graphic cards and another motherboard because the second PCI-E port I have is only PCI 2.0 (and that could be sufficient) but also only x4 lanes ... (I didn't planed at first to buy another graphic card because SLI is too expensive for the little performances improvement it gives) and maybe another power supply (because mine was dimensioned for one graphic card only, it's "only" 650W).
In the end, if I can keep my power supply, I can replace my motherboard for something around 120€ and buy a graphic card around 150-200€ that would handle PUBG with acceptable performances, this would be less expensive than buying a whole gaming computer of course.

## Conclusions

Any idea how could I perform this kind of thing with the lowest budget possible ? Considering I have a second set of peripherals for her, including a screen.

Yes I know, I want a low budget solution while I have a custom watercooling loop and a GTX 1080 Ti, but I play really often, she doesn't, I mean like, two or three times in a mounth, for this I won't consider something expensive, it's just not worth it.

Comment: If you are willing to buy another Graphics card and motherboard you already have almost a second machine. Getting a CPU and some RAM at that point shouldn't be hard. What you're looking for is hot seating/multi seating. There are some property solutions. I don't know anything about the performance. Looking into steam link might be worth it but might not work. If I'm not mistaken it also "just" streams the desktop.

Comment: Virtualization: VMWare   You can dedicate a single GPU to a single VM, but you can't share them and both get FULL hardware acceleration.  So then your problem is you need another GPU, but you lack a PSU and motherboard to drive it.  Additionally you will need 16g of RAM so both can have 8gb.  For the CPU 4 cores each is more than enough for 99% of games and you got that handled.

Comment: unRAID uses KVM to do this.  Most any Linux distro supports KVM, you'll just need to do the extra work with the configuration to get pass-through video cards to work. VMWare ESXi won't work for 1 PC as there is no console access to a VM. You'd need three systems, server and 2 clients to run the VMs.

Comment: You're right Seth, I'm not really far from having a second machine if I buy another Graphics card and motherboard, thus virtualization is not really something to consider here anymore. Buying a whole PC would work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is any good solution to have *two players at the same time* on one PC.

Anything that use remote connection (VNC, RDP, etc) will be much slower. The server - if it can even work in 3D mode - would have to receive every rendered frame from the video card, compress them, send them over the network, uncompress and finally render them on the other side. It would require some decent performance on the client side and will likely skip many frame and significantly reduce video quality. Commercial solutions may be better at this but are expensive and will likely not be enough. In any case, wireless lan will likely be a bottleneck so you'd have to consider wired connections too. Also I don't think your GPU is designed to run two games at the same time, so unless you can manage to have a 2nd dedicated GPU for this (and how would it even work??) the remote player will end up with software rending which will be much worse.

Possibly the closest you could get to native performance is with two GPUs, installing an hypervisor with PCI passthrough for the GPUs and USB passthrough for the mouse and keyboard. **I have never tested that kind of setup so I have no ideas if it would even work nor how fast it would be.** You'd have to make sure all hypervisor-related features in your BIOS are enabled. You would also need two distinct installations of Windows, possibly requiring a 2nd license. There are two possible approaches there too, none of which I tested for this use case:

1. Bare-metal hypervisor like ESXi or stripped down Linux KVM and you virtualize both Windows OS, passthrough one GPU and USB hub for each desktop. Given equal resource allocations both desktops should get equal performance.
2. Play from your bare-metal OS and run another hypervisor (ex. Hyper-V, VMWare, VirtualBox) for the VM. You will suffer less performance degradation than the VM.

Comment: As I said, the question of the GPU being enough or not is solved because I already tested it, it was good enough for me to play while she was rendering the game with RDP, the only problem was the latency of RDP in inputs and outputs plus the mouse not handled correctly. I wanted to test it with Steam local stream because I already tested it and it was not perfect but well enough for a casual gamer, but for an unknown reason (yet), I didn't manage to link the two together.
I know that GPU passthrough is possible because linus tech tips already did it, but that will force me to buy another GPU.

Comment: Plus another motherboard and possibly change my power supply too.

Comment: I didn't check your specific motherboard but AFAIK many gaming motherboards will support two GPUs. -- PSU, possibly depending on how much headroom you have - even if you don't have the 2nd GPU power plug an adapter might do.

Comment: I assume you wanted to say two GPUs. It's an MSI B350 PC Mate, the second PCI-E port I have is only a PCI-E 2.0 x4 lanes and is connected to the chipset, not directly to the CPU which is not really optimal for a second gaming graphic cards. I dimensioned my motherboard accordingly to the needs I had back then, I didn't considered to buy a second graphic card.

Comment: _Stadia has left the chat_

Answer (score 0):

There are three distinct options to consider here.

1) Virtualization

I have been using a [single system multi-seat virtualized gaming capable setup](https://altechnative.net/virtually-gaming-part-2-evolution-consolidation-and-move-to-kvm/) since many years before Linus Tech Tips discovered the idea. This works very well, but it does require you to have a separate PCU-passthrough GPU and USB controller per seat. If you have only one GPU in the system, this will not work for you.

2) Remote desktop based gaming

This requires you to have a separate machine to run the remote seat from, e.g. a laptop or desktop machine that is capable of decoding h264 in the required resolution, and with good enough network connectivity (wired gigabit ethernet). The most straightforward one is [RDP with RemoteFX](https://gist.github.com/Misairu-G/616f7b2756c488148b7309addc940b28#remotefx-configure-and-fine-tuning). You will need to deviate from that setup, enable some compression, enable H.264 444 mode for NVENC hardware compression to work via the GeForce 10xx hardware codec, and you will need [RDP Wrap to un-disable concurrent users on Windows 10](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/releases) (Note: the repository has been disabled by github, so you may have to wait for a few days for it to pop up again elsewhere). Without this, the console session will be logged out as soon as the remote RDP session connects.

3) [Multi-seat non-RDP non-virtualized gaming using Aster](https://www.ibik.ru/)

This is probably the closest to what you are trying to achieve and with a minimum number of moving parts - no need for additional computer or virtualization or even a 2nd GPU.